# Como mostrar en console.log() objeto con el resultado del metodo funcion agregado al objeto

Tags: javascript

Resolvi el ejercicio de forma correcta pero nose como mostrarlo en un console.log() para verificar los resultados. Soloobtengo esto como resultado. Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

```
     function agregarMetodoCalculoDescuento (producto) {
  // Agregar un método (función) al objeto "producto" llamado "calcularPrecioDescuento"
  // Este método debe multiplicar el "precio" del "producto" ("producto.precio" o "producto[precio]") y "porcentajeDeDescuento" para obtener el descuento
  // El método resta el descuento del precio y devuelve el precio con descuento
  // Devuelve el objeto "producto" al final de la función
  // Ejemplo:
  // producto.precio -> 20
  // producto.porcentajeDeDescuento -> 0.2 (o simplemente ".2")
  // producto.calcularPrecioDescuento() -> 20 - (20 * 0.2)
  // Tu código:
    producto.calcularPrecioDescuento = function(){
        var descuento = producto.precio * producto.porcentajeDeDescuento;
        return producto.precio - descuento;
    }
    return producto;
} 

console.log(agregarMetodoCalculoDescuento(producto));

//Solamente obtengo como resultado esto y quisiera que me devuelva
//calcularPrecioDescuento: 8 Como podria realizarlo?
//{ precio: 10,
//porcentajeDeDescuento: 0.2,
//calcularPrecioDescuento: [Function] }
```

Comment: Esto? `console.log(agregarMetodoCalculoDescuento(producto).calcularPrecioDescuento());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `agregarMetodoCalculoDescuento(producto)` te devuelve el producto con un nuevo método, puedes guardar el producto con el método que devuelve la función en otra variable y ejecutar el método en el `console.log()`.

```
const productoConMetodo = agregarMetodoCalculoDescuento(producto);
const precioConDescuento = productoConMetodo.calcularPrecioDescuento();
console.log("Precio con descuento:", precioConDescuento);
```

Se puede simplificar así:

```
console.log("Precio con descuento:", agregarMetodoCalculoDescuento(producto).calcularPrecioDescuento());
```

Para añadir el precio con el descuento al producto es tan sencillo como esto:

```
producto.precioConDescuento = producto.calcularPrecioDescuento();
console.log(producto) //Aquí ya se muestra con el precio con descuento
```

También podrías hacer que el propio método agregue la variable al producto:

```
producto.calcularPrecioDescuento = function(){
    var descuento = producto.precio * producto.porcentajeDeDescuento;
    producto.precioConDescuento = producto.precio - descuento;
}
```

Y para mostrarlo:

```
const productoConMetodo = agregarMetodoCalculoDescuento(producto);
productoConMetodo.calcularPrecioDescuento();

console.log(productoConMetodo);
```

Espero que esto resuelva tu problema.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Asi de esta manera consigo que me devuelva el resultado de la funcion solamente. Y lo que quisiera es que al retornar el producto, lo retorne ya con el resultado 8 asi  //{ precio: 10,
//porcentajeDeDescuento: 0.2,
//calcularPrecioDescuento: 8 }

Comment: @lukasr0092 Ya edité mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! Me sirvio mucho tu respuesta. No entendia donde colocar producto.calcularPrecioDescuento = producto.calcularPrecioDescuento(); pero claro, dentro de la funcion grande y antes del return producto. Gracias a la gente como vos que nos permite entender y siempre ayudan.

Comment: var producto = {
    precio: 10,
    porcentajeDeDescuento: .2,
}
function agregarMetodoCalculoDescuento (producto) {
    producto.calcularPrecioDescuento = function(){
        var descuento = this.precio * this.porcentajeDeDescuento;
        return this.precio - descuento;
    }
    producto.calcularPrecioDescuento = producto.calcularPrecioDescuento();
    return producto;
}
console.log(agregarMetodoCalculoDescuento(producto));